# Can I use cffile to copy multiple files?

Tags: coldfusion, cffile

In ColdFusion I am setting up a new directory with `<cfdirectory`.  Then I need to copy several files from one directory to the new one, keeping the same filenames.  I can use a loop to do this, but am wondering if there is any function in cffile that would allow me to copy multiple files at one time.

Cumbersome --  With reploc and newloc being source and target directories:

```
<cfdirectory
      directory  = 'newloc'
      action     = 'create'   
      mode       = 777>

<cfoutput>
<cfset extrep = ExpandPath('reploc')>
<cfset extnew = ExpandPath('newloc')>

 <cfset flist = 'a.cfm', 'b.cfm'>
 <cfloop list = '#flist#' index = 'item'>
   <cffile 
       action = "copy" 
       source = "#extrep#/#item#"
       destination = "#extnew#/#item#"
       mode = "766" >
 </cfloop>
 </cfoutput>
```

I have exactly four files to copy.  They are fixed and do not depend on any user input.

I was hoping `<cffile` would support copying multiple files, but I can't find anything that says it will.  Can anyone suggest a more streamlined approach to setting up this directory with its four files?

Comment: Is this a one off or something regular? What sort of file system is this?

Comment: It's intermittent.  It is just a generic Linux file system.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nope. As the name implies, `cffile` only operates on individual files.

However, what you could do is use [DirectoryCopy()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-c-d/DirectoryCopy.html) or [`<cfdirectory action="copy">`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-d-e/cfdirectory.html) with a file `filter`. The example below copies files "a.cfm" and "b.cfm" to the target folder.

**CFScript/CFML:**

```
 DirectoryCopy("c:\path\source", "c:\path\target", false, "a.cfm|b.cfm")
```

**CFML:**

```
<cfdirectory action="copy"
    directory="c:\path\source"
    destination="c:\path\target"
    filter="a.cfm|b.cfm">
```

Comment: Will try this shortly.

Comment: Glad it helped. Turns out there actually IS a DirectoryCopy function, it was just omitted from one of the docs.  It does the same thing and IMO is sleeker than using `<cfdirectory>`. See updated answer.